# How to check if array contains a substring php

Tags: php

I have an array of arrays as such below and I want to check if the [avs_id] contains a substring "a_b_c". How to do this in php?

```
  Array
            (
                [id] => 10003    
                [avs_id] => a_b_c_3248
            )

    Array
        (
            [id] => 10003    
            [avs_id] => d_e_f_3248
        )
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words

Comment: Is it multiple variables or is it a 3d array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter()`:

```
$src = 'a_b_c';

$result = array_filter
(
    $array,
    function( $row ) use( $src )
    {
        return (strpos( $row['avs_id'], $src ) !== False);
    }
);
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/0vuEi)**</kbd>

The result maintain original keys, so you can directly retrieve item(s) matching substring.

If you want only check if substring exists, or the number of items having substring, use this:

```
$totalMatches = count( $result );
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your array and test for the string in the specific element of your array with strpos as in the example code below.

```
foreach($yourMainArray as $arrayItem){
    if (strpos($arrayItem['avs_id'], 'a_b_c') !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop may be more ideal but if you know what array index the string is in that you are after:

```
$arr = array('id'=>'10003', 'avs_id'=>'a_b_c_3248');

if (strpos($arr['avs_id'], 'a_b_c') !== false) {
    echo 'string is in avs_id';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
foreach($yourArray as $arrayItem){
    if (strpos($arrayItem['avs_id'], 'a_b_c') !== false) {
        //return true : code here
    }
}
```